# Unable to make an input tag to submit the form and open BootStrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to submit a form to my servlet and open a BootStrap Modal at the same time with an input tag in my .jsp file. However, if I set the input tag type to "button", I cannot submit the form to my servlet. If I set the type to "submit", the BootStrap Modal does not work. Is it possible for me to do these two functions with one button?

Thanks!

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/PostController" id="getOneForUpdateForm"> 
<input class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" value="editPost">
<input type="hidden" name="postno" value="${postVO.postno}">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="getOne_For_Update">
</FORM>
```

And here is the BootStrap modal

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit the Post</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default form submission for html makes the page to reload,
But you can use jquery to submit the form and keep your page active while your modal opens up.
It is called AJAX, Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.

So i'll suggest you include jquery if you haven't,

then your form should look like this

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/PostController" id="getOneForUpdateForm"> 
<input class="btn" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" value="editPost">
<input type="hidden" name="postno" value="${postVO.postno}" id="postno">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="getOne_For_Update" id="action">
</FORM>
```

then in your script

```
$("#getOneForUpdateForm").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post(
    $("#getOneForUpdateForm").action,
    {
      name: $("#postno").val(),
      action: $("#action").val()
    },
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("form submitted");
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it does not work. It can submit the form and make the page reload but cannot open the Bootstrap modal. I also try to write a function to open the modal when the form is submitted like below. Is there anything I can try? Thanks in advance
function showModal(){
 $("#getOneForUpdateForm").submit(function(e){
    $('#EditPostModal').modal('show');
 });
 
 }